# Socket.io Not Connecting

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm wondering how I can connect to a socket.io websocket server externally. I've been using wscat to test connections but to no avail. The code I'm using is [here](http://pastebin.com/e0tCmVsL). Anyways, I've tried wscat'ing to where I deployed it, which is c9, but that hasn't worked. I've recieved an `ECONNREFUSED` error from wscat. Is there a specific thing I need to do to enable socket.io connections from outside of a page hosted on the same server? The end game is to be able to connect to the socket.io server with an iOS app.

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed your host has port 8080 open?

Comment: Yep. Thanks for taking a look at the code.

Comment: I see the server side code, but could you post the client code?  Or am I blind?

Answer (score 2):

You must use a Socket.IO library for your language. Socket.IO is not plain websockets and cannot be used as such.

Instead, look at something like: https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

Comment: This is actually pretty useful. Do you have a source, by chance?

Comment: This [link](http://davidwalsh.name/websocket) for starters should explain it for you.